# In a very long time/ for a very long time/ a very long time.

Tags: sentence-meaning

I haven't had a talk with her **in a very long time**.

I haven't had a talk with her **a very long time**.

I haven't had a talk with her **for a very long time**.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> 1 "I haven't had a talk with her in a very long time.
>
> 2 I haven't had a talk with her a very long time.
>
> 3 I haven't had a talk with her for a very long time.

"Are all the above sentences grammatically correct? What's the difference in their meaning?"

In the above examples, numbers 1 and 3 are grammatically correct and have no difference in meaning. Number 2 is incorrect because it is missing a preposition to link "a very long time" with "I haven't had a talk with her."